# Change dimension in column dataframe python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to ignore the great values and make them at the same level of others.

I have a dataframe like :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
ar = np.array([['2018-03-14T10:58:20.000Z', 2], 
               ['2018-03-14T11:58:20.000Z', 3],
               ['2018-03-14T12:58:20.000Z', 2],
               ['2018-03-14T13:58:20.000Z', 10],
               ['2018-03-14T14:58:20.000Z', 11],
               ['2018-03-14T15:58:20.000Z', 12],
               ['2018-03-14T16:58:20.000Z', 11],
               ['2018-03-14T17:58:20.000Z', 3],
               ['2018-03-14T18:58:20.000Z', 2],
               ['2018-03-14T19:58:20.000Z', 4],
              ])
df = pd.DataFrame(ar, columns = ['Date', 'weight'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['weight'] = df['weight'].astype(float)
```

I want to get the weights of the same level, like :

```
df_new =      [['2018-03-14T10:58:20.000Z', 2], 
               ['2018-03-14T11:58:20.000Z', 3],
               ['2018-03-14T12:58:20.000Z', 2],
               ['2018-03-14T13:58:20.000Z', 2],
               ['2018-03-14T14:58:20.000Z', 3],
               ['2018-03-14T15:58:20.000Z', 4],
               ['2018-03-14T16:58:20.000Z', 3],
               ['2018-03-14T17:58:20.000Z', 3],
               ['2018-03-14T18:58:20.000Z', 2],
               ['2018-03-14T19:58:20.000Z', 4],
              ])
```

How i can do that ?

Comment: What do you mean by "at the same level"? What function do you want applied to the Date column?

Comment: hi @FHTMitchell !
as you see, i have vector : 2,3,2,10,11,12,11,3,2,1
i want the vector : 2,3,2,2,3,4,3,3,2,3
overrides the large values from the first value detected

Comment: This still isn't clear: `from the first value detected`. Please explain your logic precisely.

Answer (score 0):

i assume that you want weight vector values close to each other.
you can try this code

`std=np.std(df['weight'])
for i,j in df.iterrows():
    if (j['weight'] > std):
        df['weight'][i] = j['weight']/std`

output

[image: output]